# How to set CPU limit in docker file for Windows Containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, azure-aks

I'm trying to host some `docker windows` based containers in `Kubernetes 1.17.9` and unfortunately this version won't respect CPU limit set in pod specification,

Is there any way I can set the CPU limit in the `docker` file of the windows containers ?

Comment: is it a singularity container perhaps? https://github.com/ncbi/pgap/issues/77

Answer (score 0):

Windows container's use a fair-share system for resource management and those are more guidelines than hard limits. Please read about the limitations here:

1. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/intro-windows-in-kubernetes/#v1-container
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/resource-controls